# Convert String to HashMap

Tags: java, string, serialization, dictionary, hashmap

I have to save some info to Hard Disk then load it.
To save info I do: myMap.toString --> write to filename

then I read from Disk:

```
String myFutureMap = read filename.
HashMap<Integer, MyData> = convertFromString(myFutureMap)

class MyData{
    public int sumaTiCuadrado;
    public int n;
    public int TTotal;
}
```

how can I convert the string to hashmap back?

Comment: What's the value of `myFutureMap`? Can you give us an example? Makes it easier to find a way how to convert it into desired `HashMap`. Thank you :)

Comment: He's using `Map.toString()`, so the format is described in [the JavaDocs for `AbstractMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString()).

Comment: @MickMnemonic but that explains only `{key=value,key=value}` structure, We still don't know if `MyData` has `toString` method and what output it generates. Also we don't know if there may be cases where `value` part represent inner structures like inner Maps `{foo=bar}`, or lists `[foo,bar]`.

Comment: @OP what is wrong with standard serialization: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm? Or if you want to serialize your data to readable form consider serializing it to JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `toString()` is not best choice - your `toString()` implementation should produce proper string describing structure and types of embedded elements - simply you must write all serialisation logic etc

A better option is to use some existing serialisation mechanism:

**Java Serialisation**

```
private Object convertFromBytes(byte[] value) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(value);
         ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
}

private byte[] convertToBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os)) {
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        return os.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

**Gson Serialisation**

```
private <T> T convertFromString(String value, Class<T> type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(value, type);
}

private String convertToString(Object object) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialize it to JSON, use GSON library: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/gson-example-read-and-write-json.html

EDIT:

Please rewrite your class, extract it to a separate file and it will then meet java convention and encapsulation:

```
 public class MyData {
    private int sumaTiCuadrado;

    private int n;

    private int tTotal;

    public MyData(int sumaTiCuadrado, int n, int tTotal) {
        this.sumaTiCuadrado = sumaTiCuadrado;
        this.n = n;
        tTotal = tTotal;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public int getSumaTiCuadrado() {
        return sumaTiCuadrado;
    }

    public int getTTotal() {
        return tTotal;
    }
}
```

Here is an util class for you:

```
public class JsonSerializationUtil {

private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

public static void serialize(String path, Object objectToSerialize) {
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(objectToSerialize);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
        bufferedWriter.write(jsonString);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Map<Integer, MyData> deserialize(String path) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    Map<Integer, MyData> result = null;
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder completeStringFromFile = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            completeStringFromFile.append(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, MyData>>() {
        }.getType();
        result = gson.fromJson(completeStringFromFile.toString(), type);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

And an example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, MyData> map = new HashMap<Integer, MyData>();
    map.put(1, new MyData(1, 1, 1));
    map.put(2, new MyData(2, 2, 2));
    serialize("myMap.json", map);

    Map<Integer, MyData> newMap = deserialize("myMap.json");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, MyData> mapEntry : newMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(mapEntry.getKey() + " " + mapEntry.getValue().getN());
    }
}
```

Comment: can't see anything usefull from there

Comment: thanks, I guess it works altough I can't use external librarys for this "joc"